# I need some advice for my little project flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make an action side scrolling game, i need some advice from you all.
I wrote my to do list here:

To do list:

1. Create my project's class.
2. Create hero MovieClip and class.
3. Create enemy MovieClip and class.
4. Create background level MovieClip and class.
5. Add MouseEvent, MouseClick, x y position to hero class.
6. Add x y position, a movement to right and left to enemy class.
7. Add background MovieClip to my project's class.
8. Add event and event listener, but still don't have a clue where to put it.
9. .... i don't know what's more to add to this project...

Is my to do list is bad? if yes, please tell me the right way so i can learn how to make a good plan for my project.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is start coding now!

I will find out if something is missing in the road,

best,

Alvaro